# Return the exact ID using fetch_assoc

Tags: php, pdo

I have a small problem in my code. I'm using fetch_assoc to get data from database and I need to get the ID number of each of returned values. the issue is that my code only return the ID number of the last data. Here's my code:

```
<form method="post" action="action.php">
  
  <select name="album" style="border:1px solid #CCC; font-size:11px; padding:1px">
      
       <?php

          $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
          $stmt = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
          $stmt -> execute();
          
          while($row = $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
          {
 
            $album_ID = $row['album_ID'];
            $value = $row['album_name'];         
            print "<option value ='". $value ."'>". $value. "</option>";


          }

       ?>
  
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="album_ID" value="<?php print $album_ID?>"/>
</form>
```

I would like the hidden input type holds the selected album id, but it always holds the album id of the last data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to place the id in the value od the option

```
....
while($row = $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{

    $album_ID = $row['album_ID'];
    $value = $row['album_name'];         
    print "<option value ='". $album_ID ."'>". $value. "</option>";


}

....
```

Then on the submission script (admin.php) the POST variable `album` will contain the ID, there is no need for the hidden input

Answer (score 0):

The hidden field will always contain the ID of the last row fetched.

> I would like the hidden input type
> holds the selected album id, but it
> always holds the album id of the last
> data.

To achieve this you will have to set the value of hidden field upon the change event of select box using JavaScript.

Comment: This would work but is overkill, would be best to just use the option value to the ID and forget the hidden input altogether.

Comment: @lizard, yes it will but 'Selom' wanted this. I didn't know what is his ultimate goal is? Maybe he needed to do some javascript based calculation depending upon the value selected in the option. That's why I answered in the straight way as he asked.